# CTE recursive query for two tables that has a many to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have three tables in that I need a single query to return the results properly.

The first table is a categories table that contains parent and child categories. The table allows for child tables at all levels, including child of child categories.

The second table is a files table which can belongs to the categories. This has a many-many relationship to the categories table. The files can also belong to a category that contains child categories.

The third table creates the many-many relationship between files and categories.

The first table is `Categories`:

```
CREATE TABLE Categories (
  category_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  category_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  parent_id INT NOT NULL
);
```

The second table is `Files`

```
CREATE TABLE Files (
  file_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  file_name varchar(20) NOT NULL
);
```

The third table links the Files to the Categories. A file can belong to any category and can belong to multiple Categories

```
CREATE TABLE Category_File (
  category_id INT NOT NULL,
  file_id INT NOT NULL
);
```

The tables are populated as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Categories (category_id, category_name, parent_id) VALUES
(1, 'Cat1', 0),(2, 'Cat2', 0),(3, 'Cat3', 1),
(4, 'Cat4', 2),(5, 'Cat5', 1),(6, 'Cat6', 0),
(7, 'Cat7', 5),(8, 'Cat8', 4),(9, 'Cat9', 7);

INSERT INTO Files (file_id, file_name) VALUES
(1, 'File1'),(2, 'File2'),(3, 'File3'),
(4, 'File4'),(5, 'File5'),(6, 'File6');

INSERT INTO Category_File (category_id, file_id) VALUES
(3, 1),(4, 2),(5, 3),
(9, 6),(7, 2),(5, 4),
(8, 4),(6, 1),(3, 5);
```

I need the return to display the categories ordered by name followed by the files ordered by name. Thus a query of all the records with all of the columns would result in

```
Result Set 1
[
category_id,    category_name,  file_id,    file_name   parent_id
1               Cat1            Null        Null        0
3               Cat3            Null        Null        1
3               Cat3            1           File1       Null
3               Cat3            5           File5       Null
5               Cat5            Null        Null        1   
5               Cat5            3           File3       Null    
5               Cat5            4           File4       Null
7               Cat7            Null        Null        5
7               Cat7            2           File2       Null
9               Cat9            Null        Null        7
9               Cat9            6           File6       Null
2               Cat2            Null        Null        0
4               Cat4            Null        Null        2
4               Cat4            2           File2       Null
8               Cat8            Null        Null        4
8               Cat8            4           File4       Null
6               Cat6            Null        Null        0
6               Cat6            1           File1       Null
]
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?   What was your attempt to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, my sql knowledge is not strong enough to write this query. I've played with recursive queries from this site that query one table, but by having the second table and the m-m relationship surpasses my level.

Comment: @PostalJoe It's good that you included code to create and populate the tables, but please be sure that the code doesn't have any errors... I've changed the column names so that they matches the insert scripts and also added some missing commas.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that. You are correct. I added the FK constraint at the last minute thinking it was needed in the question, but it should probably be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should work. It's built on the answer given by @Oleg but has some simplifications, and adds a level attribute to ensure the correct ordering.

I made it a community wiki as I don't want to take credit for someone elses work...

```
;with cte as
(
    select c.category_id, c.category_name, c.parent_id, cast(category_id as varchar(max)) as lvl
    from categories c where parent_id = 0 
    union all
    select ch.category_id, ch.category_name, ch.parent_id, c.lvl + ',' + cast(ch.category_id as varchar(max)) as lvl 
    from cte c join categories ch on ch.parent_id = c.category_id
)

select category_id, category_name, file_id, file_name, parent_id 
from (
    select c.category_id, c.category_name, null as file_id, null as file_name, c.parent_id, lvl
    from cte c  
    union all       
    select c.category_id, c.category_name, f.file_id, f.file_name, null, lvl
    from cte c
    join category_file cf on cf.category_id = c.category_id
    join files f on f.file_id = cf.file_id 
) a 
order by lvl, category_name, file_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @Categories table(
  category_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  parent_id INT NOT NULL
);

declare @Files table(
  file_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(20) NOT NULL
);

declare @Category_File table(
  category_id INT NOT NULL,
  file_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Categories (category_id, name, parent_id) VALUES
(1, 'Cat1',  0),
(2, 'Cat2', 0),
(3, 'Cat3', 1),
(4, 'Cat4', 2),
(5, 'Cat5', 1),
(6, 'Cat6', 0),
(7, 'Cat7', 5),
(8, 'Cat8', 4),
(9, 'Cat9', 7);


INSERT INTO @Files (file_id, name) VALUES
(1, 'File1'),
(2, 'File2'),
(3, 'File3'),
(4, 'File4'),
(5, 'File5'),
(6, 'File6');

INSERT INTO @Category_File (category_id, file_id) VALUES
(3, 1),
(4, 2),
(5, 3),
(9, 6),
(7, 2),
(5, 4),
(8, 4),
(6, 1),
(3, 5);


;with cteC as
(
    select c.category_id, c.name as category_name, cast(null as int) as file_id, cast(null as varchar(max)) as file_name, c.parent_id
    from @Categories c 
    where parent_id = 0 
    union all
    select category_id,name,file_id,file_name,parent_id
    from
    (
        select ch.category_id, ch.name, null file_id , null file_name, ch.parent_id
        from cteC c
            join @Categories ch on ch.parent_id = c.category_id

    )sq
)
select c.category_id, c.category_name, cast(null as int) as file_id, cast(null as varchar(max)) as file_name, c.parent_id
from cteC c  
union all       
select c.category_id, c.category_name, f.file_id, cast(f.name as varchar(max)), cast(null as int)
from cteC c
    join @Category_File cf on cf.category_id = c.category_id
        and c.file_id is null
    join @Files f on f.file_id = cf.file_id  
order by category_name, file_name
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I truly appreciate it; however, the rows are not returning in the correct order. For instance Row 3 (Cat3) should return before Row 2 (Cat2) as it is a child of Cat1.

Comment: Basically correct except for the ordering (plus it has some unnecessary parts).